# How to implement initial GDP variable in time-series growth regression?

Tags: time-series, stata, growth-model

I am running a regression on real GDP growth as the dependent variable. I am trying to include an initial year for GDP as an independent variable to control for the initial state of development in a time series regression focusing on one country.

How should I implement in this in STATA? i.e. What should the new Initial GDP variable look like

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you can estimate it as Delta GDP_t = Alpha + Beta GDP_0
where 0 is the initial year GDP in your single country. You first need to create a variable that takes the value of t=0 GDP for that country for all years. The beta coefficient will give your estimated effect of initial GDP on subsequent GDP growth rates.

Comment: Does this explain what the initial GDP looks like.  I sympathize with you because the question is not very clear.