# initial GDP in regression

Tags: regression, econometrics

I am wondering why in most of the literature when they measure the relationship between GDP and a certain phenomenon (For example Judicial Independence). Initial GDP is put as a first independent variable. 
Do anyone knows the justification for that?

example: GDP (over period 1990 to 2008) = initial GDP (1990) + Judicial Independence + ......

Comment: Could you give a reference to a paper and a page number where this occurs?

Comment: Related recent question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/272660/how-to-implement-initial-gdp-variable-in-time-series-growth-regression